# Is any property of orthocenter related in this question?

Tags: circles, triangles

While practicing mathematics Olympiad questions , i got the below given question . Though the solution is given , I am not able to bypass certain steps ... 
Can anyone please explain me why angle KPA and angle KQA are each equal to 90-angle A  ?
 I am not able to get this step . Awaiting for the get through ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

K is the orthocenter of ⊿APQ implies QKM is perpendicular to AP at M from Q.

Similarly, ⊿KNQ is right-angled at N. Therefore, MNQP and MKNA are cyclic quadrilaterals.

Hence, $\angle A = \angle MKP$ [ext. angle cyclic quad.]

$= 90^0 - \angle MPK$

That explains your query. If you need further help, say so.